# How to pass WP8 certification 6.5.1 on a native c++ app?

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8

My app just got rejected from WP8 store since it stops the media player when it starts (and starts playing some music of its own). This is exactly how WP8 sample, Marble Maze does it. Yet they rejected it.

Certification requirement: 6.5.1

```
When the user is already playing music on the phone when the app is launched,
the app must not pause, resume, or stop the active music in the phone MediaQueue
by calling the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaPlayer class.
```

So, how do I pass this requirement with c++ app? I can't use XNA, as numerous sources suggests to solve this problem, and the instance of mediaplayer's interface I receive has no way of knowning what is happening outside of my process.

I thought I just show a messagebox to user every time they start simply to request their permission to play music, but even messageboxes are beyond c++'s reach. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given that you can't do a "native C++ app", but only a C#/XAML application with a C++ native component, or a C++ / DirectX application (game), I don't think what you're saying is entirely correct.

A C++ / DirectX game would go under different certification requirements.

Also, XNA is not available at all on WP8, and XAudio2 (in C++) shouldn't cause this issue.

Comment: It is "a C++ / DirectX application (game)". And no, it didn't go under a different certification requirements.

Comment: I'd contact the support then, or try submitting again. The team handling submissions are sometimes not really awake.

Comment: On MSDN support forum they adviced to contact the marketplace support team to pass the certification. Thus, marking your answer to be effectively the correct one.

link to forum discussion:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IN/wpdevelop/thread/981d2024-bb96-4c8c-b165-bcee4dc4fd70

Comment: I wonder what made someone down vote my answer, as it *is* correct.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do something [like this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13828239/10893). Since you don't have access to the message box you will need to create your own UI to prompt the user, but you will need to prompt the user to pass certification. I'm guessing you might find some useful bits on how to deal with [this in this build talk](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-049).

Comment: Still, I have no access to information what's being played by the phone's media player, if anything is. Therefore, I have to ask the user every frickin' time he/she start the app if the music should be enabled or not. :|

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184838%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Requirement 6.5.1 – Initial launch functionality :

> "This requirement only applies to Windows Phone OS 7.1 and Windows
>   Phone OS 8.0 XAML apps."

Comment: Yes, it is good to see that this absurd requirement has been since lifted.