# Swift - Detect music playing, whether it's Spotify or iTunes

Tags: ios, swift, spotify, audio-player, background-music

I am currently using the following statement to detect music:

```
if MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer().playbackState == .Playing {
    print("There is music playing")
}
```

Great, however this will only work for iTunes player, and not music that might be coming from a different app, specifically talking about **Spotify**.

I don't need to know the song being played, simply whether there is anything playing at all, so I can decide whether I provide my own background music for my game or not.

Edit: ideally the solution should cover any 3rd party music program, not just Spotify.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Given [iOS: How do I detect if music is playing in any background music app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475867/ios-how-do-i-detect-if-music-is-playing-in-any-background-music-app)

the Swift version would be:

```
let isOtherAudioPlaying = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().isOtherAudioPlaying()
```

However, the [developer docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioSession/otherAudioPlaying) suggest that starting with iOS 8.0 you should use `secondaryAudioShouldBeSilencedHint` instead:

```
if (AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().secondaryAudioShouldBeSilencedHint()) {
   print("another application with a non-mixable audio session is playing audio")
}
```

Comment: can we get what is now playing by AVAudioPlayer ? or maybe getting the data ? or any other info about that ?