# Check if iOS is playing music ("Is button in control center Pause?")

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

I want to check in my app if the user is playing any music. Basically I would like to know if the button in the control center shows pause instead of play (since then the phone is playing some music). I don't want to use the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475867/ios-how-do-i-detect-if-music-is-playing-in-any-background-music-app) since that is also true when on a call for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found two ways, but **for both the Springboard is required. Since apps and tools are in a sandbox, these solutions can only be used in a Tweak that hooks into Springboard!**

First:

```
@interface SBMediaController : NSObject
+ (id)sharedInstance;
- (BOOL)isPlaying;
@end

bool isMusicPlaying = [[%c(SBMediaController) sharedInstance] isPlaying]; // this is always false if not hooked into Springboard!
```

Second (this solution is asynchronous):

```
#import <MediaRemote/MediaRemote.h> // also add MediaRemote to your XXX_PRIVATE_FRAMEWORKS

MRMediaRemoteGetNowPlayingInfo(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(CFDictionaryRef information) {
  NSDictionary *dict=(__bridge NSDictionary *)(information);
  if( dict != NULL && [dict objectForKey:(__bridge NSString *)kMRMediaRemoteNowPlayingInfoPlaybackRate] != NULL ){
    float rate = [[dict objectForKey:(__bridge NSString *)kMRMediaRemoteNowPlayingInfoPlaybackRate] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"playbackRate %f", rate);
    bool isMusicPlaying = rate > 0.0;
  }
});
```